# Trying to open a JNLP that specifies an older version of Java (1.6+) but the browser forces user to download current version of Java

Tags: java, jnlp

I have the following JNLP file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="h_t_t_p_s://xxx.com/yyy/" href="yyy.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <vendor>My Company</vendor>
    <homepage href="h_t_t_p_s://xxx.com/yyy"/>
    <description>A description</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+"
          href="h_t_t_p://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="h_t_t_p_s://xxx.com/yyy/yyy.jar" main="true" />
  </resources>
  <application-desc
    main-class="com.xxx.yyy.MainClass">
  </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

It works find if you have the current version of Java (currently 1.8 or on Ubuntu if you have 1.7 because it is the most recent version of openjdk.)
However, on Firefox or Internet Explorer on Windows 7 with Java 1.7, it forces you to install Java 1.8.
If I download the jnlp file and try to run it, you get a warning about the version, but the launch fails with:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker$StatusUnknownException
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpUtils.followRedirects(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequestEX(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.checkUpdateAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.isUpdateAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.updateFinalLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker$StatusUnknownException
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker.checkCRLs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationCheckHelper.doRevocationCheck(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationCheckHelper.doRevocationCheck(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationCheckHelper.checkRevocationStatus(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.X509TrustManagerDelegate.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.X509Extended7DeployTrustManagerDelegate.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.X509Extended7DeployTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more
```

I am hoping to deploy with a required version of 1.6+ so that users don't have to update their java just for me.

Answer (score 1):

> I am hoping to deploy with a required version of 1.6+ so that users don't have to update their java just for me.

Actually, you are doing your users a **big favor** if you force them to upgrade their Java.

Both Java 6 & Java 8 have been EOL'ed and the last publicly available builds will probably have exploitable security flaws.  This is why Firefox and Internet Explorer are making a fuss about running Java via the Java plugin.

---

As for the problem with CRL check failing, I think it might be this bug:

- http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8020390

If so, the fix is to upgrade the Java installation :-)

Answer (score 1):

> a JNLP that specifies an older version of Java

No it doesn't. `1.6+` specifies Java 1.6 *or later*.

If you want exactly 1.6, remove the `+`.

Comment: I mean that I want at least 1.6, so I think 1.6+ is correct.  Older meaning older than what the user may have installed.